# Auth0 and react

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I'm using react-router and auth0, my app.js looks like the code below. isAuthenticated if an auth0 function and based on if it's true or not I render my landing page or the logged-in application dashboard. This works almost fine but when I reload as logged in for a brief moment the landing page loads and only after the dashboard. I guess it's because they both have the '/' as the path, but how could I set my page to go to let's say http://localhost/3000/Dashboard after the login authentication?

```
import React from "react";
import LandingPage from "../Pages/LandingPage/LandingPage";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "../Pages/LandingPage/Footer";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import Navbar2 from "../Pages/LandingPage/Navbar2";
import Dashboard from "../Pages/inAppPages/Dashboard/Dashboard";

function App() {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Navbar2 />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={LandingPage} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Auth0 recently updated/cross-hosted a guide for react. It's worth a look - https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-react-user-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Found 2 answers in the docs, I was being lazy I guess.

https://auth0.com/docs/rules/redirect-users
https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/state-parameters